# How do I trap the button clicked event in my ViewModel for an ItemsSource Canvas collection?

Tags: binding, viewmodel

I have a XAML view shown below where I bind to an ObservableCollection of Buttons in my ViewModel using an ItemsSource on a Canvas. What I need to do now is when one of the buttons is clicked, set a property in my ViewModel to store which button was clicked please.

[A Sample of my Canvas Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSqwC.png)

```
 <Grid.DataContext>
        <local:MyViewModel />
    </Grid.DataContext>
    
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="tgr:AnimatedButton" >
            <Setter Property="ButtonBrush" Value="Red" />
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Position.X,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Position.Y,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <ItemsControl 
        ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredLocations
        ,NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas ClipToBounds="True"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've worked it out, I just add a handler in my ViewModel and that solves it.